# Is this a block argument?

Tags: go

I started learning [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) recently and in the [README](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/README.md) file comes the following code:

```
v1 := router.Group("/v1")
{
    v1.POST("/login", loginEndpoint)
    v1.POST("/submit", submitEndpoint)
    v1.POST("/read", readEndpoint)
}
```

I readed the [source code](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/52fcc5dbf6e94df33ad313858fb94b713e9d1b4a/routergroup.go) for the method **Group** and is like this:

```
IRouter interface {
    IRoutes
    Group(string, ...HandlerFunc) *RouterGroup
}
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the syntaxis or missing something in the code (Im pretty new in Go) but it looks like it is passing a block as the second argument, is this possible in Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The block you see in `{ ... }` is just that, a code block, not an argument to anything. The [`Group`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#RouterGroup.Group) method is variadic, and could accept any number of `HandlerFunc` arguments, but nothing is passed in here.

Since Go is block scoped, you can use blocks to create a limited variable scope. Since there are no declarations within the blocks, I see no use for this pattern here other than to cause the `HandlerFunc` assignments to be indented as a group for style reasons.

An example showing the scope of a code block:

http://play.golang.org/p/Kgpw1zCC7X

```
x := 42

{
    x := 3
    y := 4
    fmt.Println("x inside block:", x) // prints 3
}

fmt.Println("x outside block:", x) // prints 42
// fmt.Println(y) // undefined: y
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand

Answer (score -1):

The Group function  of IRouter is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). It means it can be called with any number of trailing arguments, of type HandlerFunc.

Another example of this type of function in go is [fmt.Println](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println):

Its signature is:

`func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`

so you can invoke it with a variable number of arguments:

`fmt.Println(1, 2)
fmt.Println("a" , "b" , "C")`