# Statement blocks in go

Tags: go

I'm not sure what the correct name for it is (and thus how to search for it), but I was just looking through some go code and saw it organized with statements inside of {}'s. I'm wondering what the reason is for supporting grouping statements like this?

The code looks like this:

```
// Check horizontal
{
    left_to_win := 3

    stop_1 := false
    stop_2 := false
    for x := 1; x <= 4; x++ {
        // ....
    }
}

// Check vertical
{
    left_to_win := 3

    stop_1 := false
    stop_2 := false

    for x := 1; x <= 4; x++ {
        // ...
    }
}

// Check diagonal bottom to top
{
    left_to_win := 3

    stop_1 := false
    stop_2 := false

    for x := 1; x <= 4; x++ {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the specific example it seems like it could easily be refactored into a single utility function. What's the name of this feature, and are there any good examples of times to use it?

Comment: Go is lexically scoped via blocks. It's just for variable scope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684265/is-this-a-block-argument

Comment: Note that the same feature is available in `C` and `C++` as well (Go draws certain ideas from the former).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those braces are defining a more specific scope for local variables. In your case each scope is declaring `stop_1`, `stop_2` and `left_to_win`. Without the additional curly braces you would get a compiler error saying you're redeclaring or defining those variables since you're using the short hand `:=` which declares and assigns in one statement.In this case the code could be written to instead just use `:=` on the initial declaration and then `=` for subsequent assignment which would remove the need for those scopes defined by the curly braces.

See [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) for more details.